# How to assign an item to a customer in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that basically holds the a connection between two tables. One table is a list of customers and the other table is a list of items that I want to assign to customers. 
What I need to do here is assign a item to a customer based on both there id numbers. So the customer has a customerID which I use to identify them. And each item has a id number that I want to use to identify the item.

So my question is how do I assign different coupons to each person. 
I am thinking of just either going though each customer and assigning them all the items i want them to have. And do this by each coupon. But how do I do that. I want to get the information from two different tables and combine them into one single table.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are talking about M2M relationship of 2 tables.

M2M : Many to Many.

for that you should have data table structures 
Customers (customerId, other fields here)
Coupons (couponId, other fields here)

create a new table
Coupons_to_Customers (customerId, couponId)

for interface, you need to make a form based on check boxes.

suppose, you are going to assign customers for a coupon.

Then show all customers with check boxes.

On submit, remove all records against couponID, and insert all selected CustomerId with that one couponID.

I hope it will resolve your issue.

Comment: The biggest question is should I use the customer or the coupon as the main point where i link them to . Should I apply coupons to the customers or customers to a coupon

Comment: Well, its up to data that if number of customers are easy to select for a coupon then go for customers selection as check box or if coupons are easy to select for a customer then go for that. 
Maybe you can do using Jquery Drag&Drop Plug-in.

Comment: Thank I think I will have to play around with it a bit for the best option. But you right about the M2M design of the table. Thank you I appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

You should insert the value for relation in your connection table

```
insert into your_connection_table (id_customer, id_item)
value(1,1), (1,2), (1,3);
```

You can do also with separated insert and you obtian that the customer 1 is related to items 1,2,3

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to join two tables like this:

```
    select cus.customer_id,cus.customer_name,cupon,id,cupon_description from
    (select customer_id, customer_name from customer_table) as cus
    left join
    (select customer_id,cupon_id,cupon_description from customer_cupon) as cupon
    on cus.customer_id = cupon.customer_id
```

Hope it helps..